# Ugly Swing Button Background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, transparency

I have a GUI, and the main panels have transparent backgrounds, so
one can see the background image through them. The problem is, clicking on a 
button on one of this panels, on Mac OS, where buttons have round borders, their backgrounds turn in a not-transparent color. How could I avoid this?

Here an image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make the button transparent using `setOpaque(false)`.  Never use a alpha color for a background color, Swing only deals with opaque or not opaque components, it does not know how to deal with alpha based colors.

If you use an alpha based background color, Swing does not know that 1- it's suppose to prepare the `Graphics` context correctly before painting the component and 2- that the components below the component will also need to be updated when the component changes.

Using alpha background colors will generate random and annoying paint artifacts as the complexity of the UI increases and the changes begin to occur (the UI is updated)

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() {
            JButton btn = new JButton("I'm a transparent button");
            btn.setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(btn, gbc);
            add(new JButton("I'm not a transparent button"), gbc);

            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\issue522.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

If you want to paint an translucent background, you will need to override the components `paintComponent` method and paint it yourself, making sure that the component is marked as transparent (not opaque) first